# Two ways to declare instance variables in Python?

Tags: python, instance-variables

Is there any difference in functionality and what happens behind the scenes between

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
```

and

```
class Class:
    var1 = ""
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
```

in Python?

Comment: I think the second option declares a Class.var1 variable that is share dbetween all instances.

Comment: @martineau: I don't think this is a duplicate, but would like to discuss it. The other question seems to be about how to choose between the two in a specific context, whereas this question is about *what the difference in semantics* is. The other question does seem to have a high quality answer about the semantics, that would be better applied to this question than that one.

Answer (score 13):

Let's explore a bit. This is your class:

```
class Class:
    var1 = 'in class'
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1

c = Class('in inst')
```

Accessing `c.var1` shows the `var1` from the instance:

```
>>> c.var1
'in inst'
```

It is located inside `__dict__` of `c`:

```
>>> c.__dict__
{'var1': 'in inst'}
```

The class variable `var1` is in  `__dict__` of `Class`:

```
>>> Class.__dict__['var1']
'in class'
```

Now make a class with only a class variable:

```
class Class2:
    var1 = 'in class'

c2 = Class2()
```

Since there is nothing in the instance, `var1` from the class will be used:

```
>>> c2.var1
'in class'
```

The `__dict__` of `c2` is empty:

```
>>> c2.__dict__
{}
```

Python always looks for `var1` first in the instance and than falls back to the class.

Answer (score 5):

As I pointed out in comment, the Class.var1 is a shared variable. It could be accessed for each instance as self.var1 **if you don't erase it with a non-shared variable in __init__**. Here is a sample of what happens :

```
class Test(object):
    shared = 0
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.notshared = i
    def intro(self):
        print("Shared is " + str(self.shared))
        print("NotShared is " + str(self.notshared))

test1 = Test(4)

test1.intro()
# Shared is 0
# NotShared is 4

Test.shared = 5
test1.intro()
# Shared is 5
# NotShared is 4

test2 = Test(3)
test2.intro()
# Shared is 5
# NotShared is 3
```

Be aware however that if you write the `self.shared` variable afterwards, you do not access the shared variable with `self.shared` anymore:

```
test1.shared = 12
test1.intro()
# Shared is 12
# NotShared is 4
test2.intro()
# Shared is 5
# NotShared is 3
```